# Concepts for designing a high performance social feed

Tags: database, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I'm not trying to build a social network here, but I'm wondering how someone could build a high performance social feed similar to Twitter's or Facebook's.

The issue I see is that every post in the feed would have to have two lookups per post, one to get the "post" and one to get the foreign key it references. On a loaded DB server with millions of posts, that can get slow very fast.

So, is there a better way to create a social stream?

Comment: Generally when you get to millions of posts and active users you have a lot of caching implemented so many of the requests will never touch the database.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can try is to implement something like Diaspora.
The whole system will be distributed over sevaral servers.

> Diaspora is not a single site — it’s a collection of different sites, with different URLs, run by different people. But they all run the same software, and they all talk to each other. Each server is called a “pod.” As the service grows, lots of these pods will join the Diaspora network.

[read more about Diaspora here](http://blog.joindiaspora.com/what-is-diaspora.html)